# Should I use Object.freeze on a const in ECMAScript 2015?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Despite the fact that a `const` cannot be assigned to in ECMAScript 2015, the object can be modified if it isn't frozen with `Object.freeze`.

Since a `const` is supposed to be immutable, would it make sense to add `Object.freeze` to freeze the object?
Most use cases would not require the contents being modifiable after being declared. One exception I thought of would be assigning a `class` to a `const` (e.g. `const MyClass = class MyClass {}`), in which case the properties *would* need to be changeable (at least for most uses).

I'm not talking about whether ECMAScript 2015 should be changed; I was wondering about whether I should use `Object.freeze` for `const`s in everyday code.

## Example

```
const firstNames = ['John', 'Daisy'];

firstNames = []                 // Fails silently
firstNames                      // => ['John', 'Daisy']

firstNames[0] = 'Replaced!';    // No error and it works!
firstNames                      // => ['Replaced!', 'Daisy']
```

## Example with `Object.freeze`

```
const firstNames = Object.freeze(['John', 'Daisy']);

firstNames = []                 // Throws an error
firstNames                      // => ['John', 'Daisy']

firstNames[0] = 'Replaced!';    // No error and it works!
firstNames                      // => ['Replaced!', 'Daisy']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I use Object.freeze for consts in everyday code?

**Yes**, I think that would be a good practise. It does give you the same advantages as `const` - failing on mistakes instead of carrying on (in strict mode, of course). It's also a more declarative style of code, clearly stating the intention that the object is not supposed to be mutated.

Yet, iirc frozen objects are still a bit slower than normal ones. If you have really performance-critical code, you'll have to know this. It shouldn't stop you from using `Object.freeze` in general, though<sup>1</sup>.

You shouldn't however rely on the exceptions thrown when accessing frozen objects. It's likely that you have to transpile your code to ES3 where freezing is not supported.

<sub>1) And the more people use it every day, the sooner engines will optimise this - it's overdue imo :-)</sub>

Comment: Yes, frozen objects really, **really** should be optimised - it's one of the easiest (at least in theory) optimisations you can do.